# C++ Program stopped working after reading large text in freopen

Tags: c++, io

i was generating output from txt, and the input from txt too, but, the the txt file is 79MB. I don't know why it's stopped working, and also, i use loop for the input, the line in the input text is 9.000.000 lines, so i need to loop 3000^2 , but i don't know what's wrong, it's just crashing after i compile it.
Here's the code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    freopen("hex.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("css.txt","w",stdout);
    cout << ".container{\nwidth: 3000px;\nheight: 3000px;\n}\n";
    cout << ".px{\nfloat: left;\nwidth: 1px;\nheight: 1px;\n}\n";
    string hex[3000][3000];
    for (int i=0; i<3000; i++)
    {
            for (int j=0; j<3000; j++)
            {
                cin >> hex[i][j];
            }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3000; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3000; j++)
        {
            cout << ".b" << i+1 << "k" << j+1  << "{\nbackground: "<< hex[i][j] << ";\n}" << endl << endl;
        }
```

Note: hex.txt size is 79MB, and when it stopped working, the "css.txt" (output file) is not exist, i'm sure it's crash when the program trying to reading freopen("hex.txt","r",stdin);
i use Codeblocks 16.01 also if i remove the line 5 in the code, it's still crash, and i just debug it in my codeblocks it said segmentation fault, how do i fix this? thanks!
EDIT: Problem solved by cout immediately after cin, and that's work! i didn't try using vector yet, but now i know that using string hex[3000][3000] didn't work because the space is too small.
Sorry my bad english.

Comment: The _compiler_ stopped working? Or your _application_ stopped working?

Comment: @MrEricSir i mean when i press "build and run" it shows the command prompt, but it's instantly crash, i think the application stopped working.

Comment: Do you really have to keep the whole file in memory? Copying everything from one memory and storing it in another seems like a waste... Can't you just read lines one by one? That way you don't do two loops but just one and in this one loop you process each line. Even if you have to load everything at once you still can skip the second loop (at least for now) and move the `cout` to the first loop right after `cin`

Comment: @Rogus I just didn't realize that before, now it just solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string hex[3000][3000];
Stack space is too small to allocate large arrays, you can use vector<vector<string>> to avoid this situation.
Such as

```
vector<vector<string> > hex(3000, vector<string>(3000));
```